# How to pass data from JSR223 sampler to Http Request sampler in JMeter

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, jsr223

Earlier we use to have CSV dataset config and Our Jmeter script read this seed data and prepare HTTP Request, it is working good.

But As per the current requirement we need to get data from mongodb pass those dynamic values to HTTP Request Sampler, I mean we need to build HTTp request sampler based on dynamic values from database ?

Can you please some one help me on this .

Comment: Which component are you trying to gauge the performance for? The MongoDB or the server that receives the HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

There is `vars` shorthand in the JSR223 Sampler which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in the Thread scope.

So if you do the following in JSR223 Sampler:

```
vars.put('foo', 'bar')
```

[image]

it will create `foo` JMeter Variable with the value of `bar`, you will be able to refer it as `{foo}` in the HTTP Request sampler

[image]

---

With regards to MongoDB connectivity setting up you can refer to [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) article, in order to get the mentioned test elements (MongoBD Source Config and MongoDB Script) add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
not_in_menu=org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.sampler.MongoScriptSampler,org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much beneficial of using `JSR223 Sampler` for calculation and then passing values into the `HTTP Request Sampler`.

There must be better idea to use `JSR223 Preprocessor` and `JSR223 Sampler`.
From my perspective, there are two options:

1. Use `JSR223 Sampler` directly for all calculations and fetching data from database and making `HTTP` call
2. Use `JSR223 Preprocessor` inside `JSR223 Sampler` and access values in `JSR223 Preprocessor`. This approach is very useful when some common values are calculated for different requests e.g. Authentication Signature for S3 where signature is calculated for different actions like download, upload, update file/tag etc.

For second approach, a `JSR223 Preprocessor` can be created and code written for calculating data, setting those data to `vars` and accessing into the `JSR223 Sampler`. Can refer the preprocessor example used for S3 signature calculation: [JMeter throws error 'Signature doesn't match' while uploading file to s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281747/jmeter-throws-error-signature-doesnt-match-while-uploading-file-to-s3)

It is quite easy, below are the steps to access values calculated in `JSR223 Preprocessor` into the `HTTP Request Sampler`:

1. Calculate the values and add into the `vars` which is a key value map available by `JSR223` e.g. `vars.put("key", "value")
2. Access the value in `HTTP Request Sampler` or `HTTP Header Manager` or any place by using string variable template e.g. `${key}`. It fetch the value from the `vars` map for the given key.

Although, it is easy fetch the baked data from `JSR223 Preprocessor`, my suggestion would be to use `JSR223 Sampler` instead for your use case.

With `JSR223 Sampler`, you can write code to fetch data from database and make `HTTP` request directly.

Giving code snippet for reference:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;


def x_amz_date = vars.get("x_amz_date");
def authorization = vars.get("aws_authorization");
def content_type = "plain/text";
def x_amz_security_token = <session token for s3>;
def x_amz_content_sha256 = vars.get("aws_sha256");
def host = <host name for s3 service>;
def content_length = vars.get("aws_content_length");

def url = "https://" + host + "/" + <bucket> + "/" + <path or directory> + "/" + <file name in s3>


log.info("x_amz_date : " + x_amz_date);
log.info("authorization : " + authorization);
log.info("content_type : " + content_type);
log.info("x_amz_security_token : " + x_amz_security_token);
log.info("x_amz_content_sha256 : " + x_amz_content_sha256);
log.info("host : " + host);
log.info("content_length : " + content_length);
log.info("url : " + url);


    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig
        .custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(10000)
        .setSocketTimeout(10000)
        .build();

    //byte array for the file which need to be uploaded in s3
    byte[] data = ("X5O!P%@AP<insert>[4\\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}\044EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!\044H+H*".replace("<insert>", "")).getBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(inputStream);
    

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = RequestBuilder
        .put()
        .setConfig(requestConfig)
        .setUri(url)
        .setHeader("X-Amz-Date", x_amz_date)
        .setHeader("Authorization", authorization)
        .setHeader("Content-Type", content_type)
        .setHeader("X-Amz-Security-Token", x_amz_security_token)
        .setHeader("X-Amz-Content-Sha256", x_amz_content_sha256)
        .setHeader("Host", host)
        //.setHeader("Content-Length", content_length)
        .setEntity(entity);

    HttpUriRequest request = requestBuilder.build();
    
    HttpClientBuilder
        .create()
        .build()
        .withCloseable { 
            httpClient -> 
            httpClient.execute(request)
                .withCloseable{ response -> 
                    String res = "RESPONSE:" + "\n"+response.getStatusLine()+"\n"+"Headers: "+response.getAllHeaders();
                    log.info("--------Result: " + res)
                    result.put("result", res)
        }
    }


result
```