# JMeter throws error 'Signature doesn't match' while uploading file to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jmeter, performance-testing

Can anyone help me figure out what is happening?

I am trying to load test an application where a user can upload and download files.

Journey:

Step-1:When a user choose a file from disk (POST request) it creates a fileID and path with uuid.

Response looks like:
`{"id":"FILE-VX-1234","path":"uuid/filename.jpg","uri":["s3://{location}/{uuid}/{filename}?endpoint=s3.dualstack.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"],"state":"OPEN","size":-1,"timestamp":"2020-02-13T10:59:43.146+0000","refreshFlag":1,"storage":"STORAGEID","metadata":{}`

Step-2:Using these (POST request) which responds with a s3 uri with assesskeyID, secretaccesskey and sessionToken.

Response looks like:
`{"uri":["s3://{accesskeyID}:{secretaccesskey}@{storage location}/{uuid}/{filename}?endpoint=s3.dualstack.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com&sessionToken={security token}"]}`

Step-3:Using these and added temporary parameters (date), a PUT request uploads a file in s3 bucket.

Header looks like:

```
Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${accesskeyID}/${currentDate}/{region}/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-user-agent, Signature=${secretaccesskey}

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 145541

Content-Type: image/jpeg

Host: <the host address>

Origin: https://{url}

Referer: https://{url}/upload/

Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors

Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36

X-Amz-Content-Sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD

X-Amz-Date:${currentDateInUTC}

x-amz-security-token: ${sessionToken}

X-Amz-User-Agent: aws-sdk-js/2.409.0 callback
```

Error:
`<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>`

I have verified that the signature(secretaccesskey), accesskeyID and sessionToken which are passed in PUT request are correct.

*Note: Additional parameters date and "{region}/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-user-agent" in Authorisation error are hardcoded.*

Comment: Hi All! Any help here?
My progress is that in theory this should be working as I am passing all parameters.  However, it would be better/easier to use some lib to get the authorization header  working. I also found example in [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html). 
Regardless, it would be helpful if anyone can point me to right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to provide any assistance without seeing how do you generate the signature for the request, to wit this [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header

As per [Signing and Authenticating REST Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) article

> The Amazon S3 REST API uses a custom HTTP scheme based on a keyed-HMAC (Hash Message Authentication Code) for authentication. To authenticate a request, you first concatenate selected elements of the request to form a string. You then use your AWS secret access key to calculate the HMAC of that string. Informally, we call this process "signing the request," and we call the output of the HMAC algorithm the signature, because it simulates the security properties of a real signature. Finally, you add this signature as a parameter of the request by using the syntax described in this section.

Here is a pseudo-code demonstrating how the header needs to be generated:

```
Authorization = "AWS" + " " + AWSAccessKeyId + ":" + Signature;

Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKey, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) );

StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    Date + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
    CanonicalizedResource;

CanonicalizedResource = [ "/" + Bucket ] +
    <HTTP-Request-URI, from the protocol name up to the query string> +
    [ subresource, if present. For example "?acl", "?location", "?logging", or "?torrent"];

CanonicalizedAmzHeaders = <described below>
```

You can check [How to Handle Dynamic AWS SigV4 in JMeter for API Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-dynamic-aws-sigv4-in-jmeter-for-api-testing/) article for example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS is now supporting the Signature version 4 which requires to be generated while uploading file to S3 bucket.

There are two type of credential you can use while upload:

- Service credential which are combination of: accessKey, secretKey, serviceName and region
- Temporary credential which are combination of: accessKey, secretKey, serviceName, sessionToken and region

In both of the cases you need to add JSR223 Preprocessor under the HTTP Request Sampler.

Add the below code to JSR223 Preprocessor and provide the required details:

```
import javax.crypto.Mac
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import java.security.InvalidKeyException
import java.security.MessageDigest
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat


//Defined in User Defined Variables
def access_key = <access key>
def secret_key = <secret key>
def host = <host>
def service = "s3"
def region = "us-east-1"
def token = <session token>
def localfile = <absolute path for local file>
def fileData = readBinaryFile(localfile)

//Create SHA256 of file data
def contentSha256 = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(fileData)
vars.put("aws_sha256", contentSha256)
vars.put("aws_content_length", fileData.length + "")


log.info("access key: " + access_key)
log.info("secret_key: " + secret_key)
log.info("host: " + host)
log.info("service: " + service)
log.info("region: " + region)
log.info("file: " + props.get("file_1.jpg"))
log.info("file sha256: " + contentSha256)
log.info("token: " + token)
log.info("content-length: " + fileData.length)


//Obtain data form the Http Request Sampler
def method = sampler.getMethod()
def url = sampler.getUrl()
def req_path = url.getPath()
def req_query_string = orderQuery(url)
def request_parameters = '';

sampler.getArguments().each {arg ->
    request_parameters = arg.getStringValue().substring(1)
}

//Create the variable x-amz-date 
def now = new Date()
def amzFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'" )
def stampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd" )
amzFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  //server timezone
def amzDate = amzFormat.format(now)
def dateStamp = stampFormat.format(now)
vars.put("x_amz_date", amzDate)


//Create a Canonical Request
def canonical_uri = req_path
def canonical_querystring = req_query_string
def canonical_headers = "host:" + host + "\n" + "x-amz-date:" + amzDate + "\n"
canonical_headers = "host:" + host + "\n" + "x-amz-content-sha256:" + contentSha256 + "\n" + "x-amz-date:" + amzDate + "\n" + "x-amz-security-token:" + token + "\n"


//def signed_headers = "host;x-amz-date"
def signed_headers = "host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token"
def payload_hash = getHexDigest(request_parameters)
def canonical_request = method + "\n" + canonical_uri + "\n" + canonical_querystring + "\n" + canonical_headers + "\n" + signed_headers + "\n" + contentSha256

log.info("---------canonical_request-------: " + canonical_request)

//Create the String to Sign
def algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
def credential_scope = dateStamp + "/" + region + "/" + service + "/" + "aws4_request"
def hash_canonical_request = getHexDigest(canonical_request)
def string_to_sign = algorithm + "\n" +  amzDate + "\n" +  credential_scope + "\n" +  hash_canonical_request


log.info("------string to sign-----: " + string_to_sign)


//Calculate the String to Sign

log.info("------datestamp to sign----: "+ dateStamp)

def signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, dateStamp, region, service)

log.info("------key to sign----: "+ org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(signing_key))

def signature = hmac_sha256Hex(signing_key, string_to_sign)

//Add Signing information to Variable
def authorization_header = algorithm + " " + "Credential=" + access_key + "/" + credential_scope + ", " +  "SignedHeaders=" + signed_headers + ", " + "Signature=" + signature
vars.put("aws_authorization", authorization_header)


def hmac_sha256(secretKey, data) {
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "HmacSHA256")
    mac.init(secretKeySpec)
    byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes())
    return digest
}

def hmac_sha256Hex(secretKey, data) {
    def result = hmac_sha256(secretKey, data)
    return result.encodeHex()
}

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
    def kDate = hmac_sha256(("AWS4" + key).getBytes(), dateStamp)
    def kRegion = hmac_sha256(kDate, regionName)
    def kService = hmac_sha256(kRegion, serviceName)
    def kSigning = hmac_sha256(kService, "aws4_request")
    return kSigning
}

def getHexDigest(text) {
    def md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    md.update(text.getBytes())
    return md.digest().encodeHex()
}

public static String orderQuery(URL url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    def orderQueryString = "";
    Map<String, String> queryPairs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String queryParams = url.getQuery();

    if (queryParams != null) {
        String[] pairs = queryParams.split("&");
    
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
            queryPairs.put(URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8"));
        }
        def orderQueryArray = new TreeMap<String, String>(queryPairs);
        orderQueryString  = urlEncodeUTF8(orderQueryArray)
    }
    return orderQueryString;
}

public static String urlEncodeUTF8(String s) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
    }
}

public static String urlEncodeUTF8(Map<?,?> map) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<?,?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append("&");
        }
        sb.append(String.format("%s=%s",
            urlEncodeUTF8(entry.getKey().toString()),
            urlEncodeUTF8(entry.getValue().toString())
        ));
    }
    return sb.toString();       
}



public static byte[] readBinaryFile(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath)
    byte[] binaryContent = file.bytes
    return binaryContent
}
```

Provide the below parameters into the preprocessor:

```
def access_key = <access key>
def secret_key = <secret key>
def host = <host>
def service = "s3" //is any specific name given for service else it will be s3 by default
def region = "us-east-1" //the required region
def token = <session token>
def localfile = <absolute path for local file>
```

Then add the HTTP Header Manager into the HTTP Request Sampler where add the below headers:

```
Header Name:    Value
X-Amz-Date: ${x_amz_date}
X-Amz-Security-Token: ${sessionToken}
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: ${aws_sha256}
Authorization: ${aws_authorization}
Content-Length: ${aws_content_length}
Content-Type: <file content type>
Host: ${host}
```

Here, below header's value calculated dynamically when file comes to upload by the preprocessor:

- X-Amz-Date
- X-Amz-Content-Sha256
- Authorization
- Content-Length

Now, In HTTP Request sampler set the request method (normally PUT), protocol (e.g. https), server (...s3.service.com), port (e.g. 443), path (path of the file including bucket name).

Click on File Upload tab in HTTP Request Sampler, profile the absolute path of local file which need to be uploaded and provide the mime type.

Note: Do not provide parameter name (it will be blank as file will go in raw binary format) and Use multipart/form data checkbox should be unchecked as file is going in raw format.

Just to give a little more help, you can use `JSR223 Sampler` for making `HTTP` request with different file upload / download approach. E.g. Uploading dynamically calculated data as file. Refer the link: [How to pass data from JSR223 sampler to Http Request sampler in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236713/how-to-pass-data-from-jsr223-sampler-to-http-request-sampler-in-jmeter)

Hope it will help you.